# MongoDb _id field rename

Tags: mongodb, mongotemplate, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a collection named 'summary' in azure cosmos db and _id field for my collection is 'orderId'. I have millions of records in my collection. Now I want to rename my _id field 'orderId' to 'purchaseOrderId'(as per business domain design). This collection has '_id.orderId' index. To achieve this one straight approach is dropping the collection and reload with new id field name, but that cost more and also time consuming since it needs to reload millions of data. So is there any way to achieve this by updating _id field name for rename (by retrieving existing record and do a rename update)with spring mongotemplate or mongodb driver 3.11.1.

old id field name  : 'orderId',

recommended id name : 'purchaseOrderId',

Existing index : '_id.orderId',

Mongo db version: 3.6

Mongo document structure

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "orderId" : 10164
    },
    "countryCode" : null,
    "sequenceNumber" : "5693",
    "deptNumber" : "92",
    "type" : "20",
    "addrNumber" : 12,
    "venNumber" : 0,
    "shipPtDescr" : "                              ",
    "whsNumber" : "6001",
    "purchId" : 1006,
    "statCode" : "C",
    "groceryId" : "N",
    "openToBuyMonth" : 12,
    "updateSource" : "MF",
    "authorizedDate" : null,
    "deposit" : null,
    "cost" : null,
    "boardCode" : null,
    "authorizedBy" : null,
    ... 
    ..
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **_id** is an immutable field in MongoDB and it does not allow to change the **_id** of a document after you have inserted it.

Here is the behavior of **_id** field as mentioned in [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/) :

***_id Field*** 
Once set, you cannot update the value of the _id field nor can you replace an existing document with a replacement document that    has a different _id field value.

As a work-around, let MongoDB create it's own **_id** field while you add another field ( say, ***custom_id*** outside **_id** field ) that your application will refer and use.

```
{
    "_id" : Object("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
    "custom_id" : {
        "orderId" : 10164
    },
    "countryCode" : null,
    "sequenceNumber" : "5693",
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here you can rename the field as

```
db.collection.updateMany( {}, { $rename: { "custom_id.orderId": "custom_id.purchaseOrderId" } } )
```